# What is the difference between "prix" and "tarif" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

From my time here in Paris it seems that *tarif* is more used for tickets than anything else, but I'm not 100% clear. Is it just services in general where *tarif* is used instead of *prix*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le tarif c'est l'ensemble des différents prix fixés pour une marchandise ou une prestation.

Prenons le métro parisien par exemple, il y a différents tarifs, normal, jeune, ticket+, navigo etc...  Le prix du billet jeune weekend est de 4 euros.

Un artisan doit afficher le tarif de ses prestations et chacune de ses prestations a un prix (c'est à dire un coût différent).

Ce qui peut être source de confusion pour une anglophone c'est qu'en anglais on emploie *price* pour parler du prix/coût d'un objet, d'une prestation, et *price**s*** pour parler de tarif(s)

Answer (score 2):

The *prix* is what you pay for something.

A *tarif* is a list giving the price or fees for available goods, services or actions (in English I think *price list* is used for that meaning, at least in commercial contexts).  The word is also used for the price in such a list for a given item (in English *list price*).

The list is often the official one, but in contexts where you may expect a wide difference between the official price and the price you really pay or where different sources have vastly different prices, *tarif* is also used informally for the price you can expect to pay if you negotiate correctly or search for a correct source.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, I'd say it's the difference between fee and price.

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language SE. What is the new information in your answer compared to the already available answers? And which of the translations you have provided correspond with which of the French words in the question?